# How can I enable the audit logging in LDAP

Tags: ldap

I want to log the users activities (who does what) on LDAP, the audit log is disabled by default, how can I enable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going from previous questions i presume you're using IPA.

Audit logging is configured through the directory server itself - you just need to set the relevant attribute from "off" to "on".

The object is "cn=config" and the attribute is *nsslapd-auditlog-logging-enabled*, which is set to "off" by default. Just set it to "on" with an ldapmodify or your favourite 3rd-party LDAP editor.

All other log-tuning (size, directory etc) is there too, i can't find a non-pdf guide on the web right now. This setting also works for Oracle/Sun Directory Server.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful, and I found this page that discribes all those attributes
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Directory_Server/8.1/html/Configuration_and_Command_Reference/Configuration_Command_File_Reference-Core_Server_Configuration_Reference-Core_Server_Configuration_Attributes_Reference.html